# A query about serial data transmission

Tags: terminology, communication-protocols

I was studying computer science and I learnt that Serial Data transmission is when one bit is transmitted at a time over one wire/channel. Then what does '8 bit serial' data transmission mean?
I was studying about MIDI where it said it uses 8 bit serial data transmission and is asynchronous.

Also, I cannot seem to find an appropriate tag to set to this question.

Comment: I've never heard of "8-bit serial data transmission".  When I google "8-bit serial" all I find are 7400-series 8-bit shift registers.  They have a serial input, 8-bits of storage, and (usually) 8-bit parallel output.  You have a slightly better chance of getting an answer if you ask the mods to migrate this to electronics.stackexchange.com, but you should edit the question to give context, like where you heard of "8-bit serial data transmission" (give a reference that people can look at for themselves.)

Comment: Downvoter reason for downvote? And this is in my Computer Science textbook

Comment: ??? I gave you the reason for the downvote.  You asked a question without the necessary context (the _reference_ to the textbook: author's name, book title, year published, page number that contains the term, and a quotation of the paragraph that contains the term and is confusing you.)

Comment: I see you edited to say that this question is specifically about MIDI protocol.  For that you should definitely ask the moderators to migrate the question to electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok @Wandering Logic but how?

Comment: looks like you got an answer, so not necessary.  If you do need to migrate in future click where it says "flag" on the lower-left side of the question.  That will give you options including one to request moderator attention and send a short note to the moderators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was probably a rather unfortunate abbreviation of [8-N-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-N-1) serial transmission which is what [MIDI uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_1.0). The 8 bits are sent serially, one at time, still.